# Multiple INSERT INTO query

Tags: php, mysql

Is there a way to have a dymanic insert function using PHP?

I've got a function that deals with several files that follow the same structure, but not always have the same number of values. For example, if a file has 10 values it will write to a certain table, if it has 3 it will write to another.

I have thought about a switch block, something on the lines of this pseudo-code:

```
function($table)
{
     $n_values = (number of values read from the file);
     switch($n_values)
     {
          case 1: $query = "INSERT INTO ".$table." VALUES('')";
                  break;
          case 2: $query = "INSERT INTO ".$table." VALUES('', '')";
                  break;
          (...)
     }
     $query->run();
}
```

However this block only deals with the cases that are hard coded. I was wondering if there is a way to manipulate the query and having it set to adapt to the number of values read from the file and appoint to write to the proper table?

EDIT: I managed to develop the dynamic system that I wanted, it was possible appendig the values I wanted to a string and then running the string. I changed the code a little (only the part that dealt with this subject is here), so it shouldn't work if copied and pasted, but there's an idea of how I did it. Cheers for the answers.

```
 function func($table)
 {
       open_file($file_name);
       //while (!$file_name->eof())
       {
            $line = explode(" ", trim($file->fgets()));
            $query = "INSERT INTO `".$table."` VALUES ('' "; //1st value is an a.i. id 
            for($i = 0 ; $i < get_num_values($file_name)); $i++)
            {
                $query = $query.', ' .$line[($i)]. '';
            }
            $query = $query . ')';
            $stmt = $con->query($query);
        }
 }
```

Comment: what is the table structure and what values you are getting??

Comment: You would have to specify which "columns" are contained in the specific value. Then you could fill the query with dynamic columns and dynamic values.

Comment: there will be several tables, each for the number of values. the table is known prior to the function being called and I still haven't coded this, I'm just exploring the options. 

I think I understood what you meant @Adimeus.

Comment: sounds like a very bad system. but anyway, you will have to hardcode the table names, or make them have a structured name based on the col count. the info in your question is not sufficient.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Possible solution.

This uses an array storing the table names for each number of columns.

It also uses a class to insert multiple rows at once (it is quite a lot faster to insert 250 rows in one insert statement than it is to do 250 separate inserts).

It loops around the list of tables and creates a new instance for each one.

Then it reads the file. For each row it calls the make_row method of the object for the file with that number of columns. The class of the object will do an insert when it has a certain number of rows to insert (by default 255 - easy to change), and will also do an insert when the __DESTRUCT is called.

Once the input file is completed it loops around the table objects and unsets them all (which triggers the __DESTRUCT for each one, clearing out any remaining inserts).

```
<?php

$table_names = array(1=>'Table1Col', 2=>'Table2Col', 3=>'Table3Col', 4=>'Table4Col', 5=>'Table5Col' );
$table_process = array();

foreach($table_names as $table_col_count=>$table_name)
{
    $table_process[$table_col_count] = new table_process($con, $table_name);
}

open_file($file_name);
while (!$file_name->eof())
{
    $line = explode(" ", trim($file->fgets()));
    $table_process[count($line)]->make_row($line);
}

foreach($table_process as $table_process_name)
{
    unset($table_process_name);
}

class table_process
{

    var $db;
    var $row_array = array();
    var $field_name_store = '';
    var $table_name = '';
    var $record_count = 0;
    var $update_clause = '';
    var $rows_to_process = 255;

    function __CONSTRUCT($db, $table_name, $update_clause = '')
    {
        $this->db = $db;
        $this->table_name = $table_name;
        $this->update_clause = $update_clause;
    }
    function __DESTRUCT()
    {
        if (count($this->row_array) > 0)
        {
            $this->process_rows();
        }
    }
    function field_names($in_field_names)
    {
        $this->field_name_store = "(`".implode("`,`", $in_field_names)."`)";
    }
    function record_count()
    {
        return count($this->record_count);
    }
    function make_row($in_row)
    {
        $ret = true;
        foreach($in_row AS &$in_field)
        {
            $in_field = (($in_field == null) ? "NULL" : "'".$this->db->escape($in_field)."'");
        }
        $this->record_count++;
        $this->row_array[] = "(".implode(",", $in_row).")";
        if (count($this->row_array) > $this->rows_to_process)
        {
            $ret =  $this->process_rows();
        }
        return $ret;
    }
    function process_rows()
    {
        $ret = true;
        $sql = "INSERT INTO ".$this->table_name." ".$this->field_name_store." VALUES ".implode(",", $this->row_array)." ".$this->update_clause;
        if (!$this->db->query($sql))
        {
            $ret = false;
        }
        $this->row_array = array();
        return $ret;
    }
    public function set_rows_to_process($rows_to_process)
    {
        if (is_numeric($rows_to_process) and intval($rows_to_process) > 0)
        {
            $this->rows_to_process = $rows_to_process;
        }
    }
}

?>
```

The class expects a database class with a query method. Should be easy for you to change it to match the connection you are using.

Comment: I'll look into your code and try and understand the logic of it. Mainly because my code lacks eficiency (like you suggested) and I need to boost the transfer speed rates. Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want a variety of INSERT statement that can discern automatically which table to use from the number of data items (and maybe the type of data items) presented in an input file.

The answer to your question: No, SQL doesn't do that.

From your question, you are well on your way to creating a client program that's specific to your application that will do what you want. Writing your own program is the correct approach: you can control the table selection logic and the error-handling with knowledge of the details of your application.

Answer (score 0):

**Array based approach**

Instead of appending a number to the field, use an array based approach:

```
<form action="" method="POST">
    <b>Product 1</b><br
    <label>Product Id <input type="text" name="products[0][id]"></label>
    <br>
    <label>Product Type <input type="text" name="products[0][type]"></label>
    <br>            
    <b>Product 2</b><br>
    <label>Product Id <input type="text" name="products[1][id]"></label>
    <br>
    <label>Product Type <input type="text" name="products[1][type]"></label>
</form>
```

Now if you were to submit this to PHP and do print_r($_POST['products']);, you would get something like the following:

```
array(
    0 => array(
        'id' => '...',
        'type' => '...',
    ),
    1 => array(
        'id' => '...',
        'type' => '...',
    )
)
```

This allows you to do the logic for the insertion once, and then use a loop to do all of the fields.

The (pseudo) code would be like:

```
$products = (isset($_POST['products']) && is_array($_POST['products'])) ? $_POST['products'] : array();

//Note that I've assumed the id column is an int, and the type column is a string.
//In real schema, I would expect type to also be an int, but I want to illustrate proper escaping.
//(There is more on this in a later section)
$query = "INSERT INTO products (id, type) VALUES (%d, '%s')";

foreach ($products as $product) {
    //Ensure that $product contains a valid entry, and if it does not, store errors somewhere
    if (valid entry) {
        $res = mysql_query(sprintf($query, (int) $product['id'], mysql_real_escape_string($product['type'])));
        if (!$res) {
            //Log an error about the query failing
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function func($table)
{
    open_file($file_name); 
    $line = explode(" ", trim($file->fgets()));
    $values = "'','".implode("','", $line)."'";

    $query = "INSERT INTO `{$table}` values ({$values})";

    $stmt = $con->query($query);
}
```

or instead of exploding then imploding, just replace replace the " " in the file contents with ',' and add on to the front and back an additional '.  however, your exploding will cause problems if there is every a space for the contents.  if your database doesn't like quoted numerals, you might have to modify to not quote numerals.

```
function func($table)
{
    open_file($file_name); 
    $values = "'','".str_replace(' ', "','", trim($file->fgets()))."'".

    $query = "INSERT INTO `{$table}` values ({$values})";

    $stmt = $con->query($query);
}
```